# RecyclerView with TableRows inside

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to make 4 horizontally-scrollable TableRows, where each column in all rows has same width (depending on largest view from this column). First I did next structure: ScrollView -> TableLayout -> TableRow(s) -> items. But when I try to update a lot of child views in table UI freezes. How it's possible to do the same thing using RecyclerView or something similar?
[image]

Comment: How about using a RecyclerView with a LinearLayoutManager with orientation [HORIZONTAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#HORIZONTAL)?

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView setting:

```
    adapter = new BitAdapter(list);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false);
    final RecyclerView myList = findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
    myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    myList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

.+ usual RecyclerView.Adapter